# How to place an imageview on top of another imageview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

This is my layout which i tried so far without any success

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white">

 <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/lltest" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/inside_imageview" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:src="@drawable/frame"/>

</LinearLayout>

 <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/outside_imageview" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/inside_imageview"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What i exactly want is to have my outside_imageview on top of inside_imageview with the exact height and width... How to do it through layout?

Comment: have you tried adding layout_alignLeft="@id/inside_imageview" in addition to the alignTop?

Comment: The issue was he has the inside_imageView inside a LinearLayout so the attribute `layout_alignTop` can't see the reference ID to `inside_imageView`.  `outside_imageview` would align to the LinearLayout if the ID references was `lltest` instead.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
    <RelativeLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="@color/white" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/inside_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:src="@drawable/frame" />

      <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/outside_imageview"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignTop="@id/inside_imageview"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@id/inside_imageview"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@id/inside_imageview"
         android:layout_alignRight="@id/inside_imageview"            
         android:scaleType="fitXY" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

The `layout_align[Top|Bottom|Left|Right]` attribute in `RelativeLayout` is used to align views based on their respective x and y values within the margin.  The second `ImageView` will now be aligned to the top, bottom, left, and right of the first `ImageView` based on the margins.  Padding is ignored in the alignment.

Comment: Hmmm... Actually I have two more imageviews along with inner_imageview... so i thought of putting them in a seperate linearlayout... The inner one i need to do a horizontal orientation and the outer one i want a vertical... So please suggest me in this

Comment: That complicates things a bit more.  You can't reference views that are children in other views.  They only accept references to children in the same level.  If `inside_imageview` and `outside_imageview` are the same width and height, then you merely need to put them both in two separate `Linearlayouts` and align two `LinearLayouts` by the top and left.  If the dimensions are widely different, then you may have to use `layout_below` for one and `layout_toRightOf` for the other.

Comment: great answer ! love it !

Answer (score 21):

[`FrameLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) is what you need. You can simply merge the parent layout that is a `FrameLayout` too.
Take a look at the **Android Developers Blog**: http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/outside_imageview" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/inside_imageview" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:src="@drawable/frame" />
</merge>
```

Comment: sadly the guy that asked the question, doesn't understands and doesn't even wants to understand what frame layout can do and downvoted us all. upvoted u two guys :)

Comment: This even reduces the view hierarchy by one level :woot:

Comment: Nice solution. The FrameLayout is certainly the way to go.

Comment: @Francesco Vadicamo Could I please ask, I am having rendering problems. An exception is being raised which suggests that <merge> must be the root element. I don't need all elements to be on top of each other. I just need the 2 images to be neseted. Currently, the root element is a vertical LinearLayout and I would like to maintain the ordering of the child elements. What should I do?

Comment: @Francesco Vadicamo I tried including a different layout with merge as the root element and (show_in activity_main) but the layout is not being included

Comment: @JqueryNinja `<merge>` is used when you need a `FrameLayout` so you want to reuse the root `FrameLayout` that Android anyhow puts on top of the hierarchy; if you need a `LinearLayout`, simply add it as the root element of your layout, you don't need to use `<merge>`

Answer (score 6):

You should try a `FrameLayout`. Inside a FrameLayout every Child is on top of each other.

Comment: only 1 image is being shown on the device and 2 images, one on top of the other are being shown correctly in the design view of the layout

Answer (score 3):

I tried this way and it worked for me,hope it helps

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_first"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/imga"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: only 1 image is being shown on the device and 2 images, one on top of the other are being shown correctly in the design view of the layout

Comment: so whts the issue

Answer (score 3):

I use  Elevation only... 0=floor or basement ... lol 1=floor2 10=floor10 the top top

```
    <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/blog_user_image_gp"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="200dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
          android:src="@drawable/avatar"
          android:scaleType="fitXY"
          android:foregroundGravity="center"
          android:elevation="10dp"
          />
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/users_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
                <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="@dimen/_15dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/white_background"
                   />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_100dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_100dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/my_credit"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it places an imageview on the above  of another imagview... there is no need to use any frame layout

Answer (score -1):

Just add translation z and it will be on top, make sure the translation z is greater than the view you want to be on top of. Sorry for the late response.