# How to add sticky header in listview with background image on list row in android?

Tags: android, sticky

I am trying to add sticky header in listview. I implemented that with the help of code which I found at https://github.com/beworker/pinned-section-listview

Below is the picture in which I got the listview row as [image]

Its working fine but I need to customize above row. there are two separate layout for a single row which are a.) listheader.xml   b.) listrow.xml  both the xml are two separate parts of a single row of listview.

Now what I want to do is that list row header should be with transparent background(listheader.xml) and  listrow.xml should not have the background image of a guy carrying camera. the image should be set to background of each listview row. which will look like below
[image]

so my listview row will have a background image and a header not above image but over the image as you can see in the above image.
can anybody tell me how can I do that.
below is my code of adapter I used.

```
public abstract class SectionAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
        OnItemClickListener {

    private int mCount = -1;

    Context context;

    public SectionAdapter(Context c) {
        this.context = c;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public abstract int numberOfSections();

    public abstract int numberOfRows(int section);

    public abstract View getRowView(int section, int row, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent);

    public abstract Object getRowItem(int section, int row);

    public boolean hasSectionHeaderView(int section) {
        return false;
    }

    public View getSectionHeaderView(int section, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        return null;
    }

    public Object getSectionHeaderItem(int section) {
        return null;
    }

    public int getRowViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    public int getSectionHeaderViewTypeCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Must return a value between 0 and getRowViewTypeCount() (excluded)
     */
    public int getRowItemViewType(int section, int row) {
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Must return a value between 0 and getSectionHeaderViewTypeCount()
     * (excluded, if > 0)
     */
    public int getSectionHeaderItemViewType(int section) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    /**
     * Dispatched to call onRowItemClick
     */
    public final void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        onRowItemClick(parent, view, getSection(position),
                getRowInSection(position), id);
    }

    public void onRowItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int section,
            int row, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    /**
     * Counts the amount of cells = headers + rows
     */
    public final int getCount() {
        if (mCount < 0) {
            mCount = numberOfCellsBeforeSection(numberOfSections());
        }
        return mCount;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return getCount() == 0;
    }

    @Override
    /**
     * Dispatched to call getRowItem or getSectionHeaderItem
     */
    public final Object getItem(int position) {
        int section = getSection(position);
        if (isSectionHeader(position)) {
            if (hasSectionHeaderView(section)) {
                return getSectionHeaderItem(section);
            }
            return null;
        }
        return getRowItem(section, getRowInSection(position));
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    /**
     * Dispatched to call getRowView or getSectionHeaderView
     */
    public final View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        /*
         * RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(context); LayoutParams
         * listParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
         * LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); rl.setLayoutParams(listParams);
         * convertView = (View)rl;
         */

        int section = getSection(position);
        if (isSectionHeader(position)) {
            if (hasSectionHeaderView(section)) {
                return getSectionHeaderView(section, convertView, parent);
            }
            return null;
        }
        return getRowView(section, getRowInSection(position), convertView,
                parent);
        // return convertView;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the section number of the indicated cell
     */
    protected int getSection(int position) {
        int section = 0;
        while (numberOfCellsBeforeSection(section) <= position) {
            section++;
        }
        return section - 1;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the row index of the indicated cell Should not be call with
     * positions directing to section headers
     */
    protected int getRowInSection(int position) {
        int section = getSection(position);
        int row = position - numberOfCellsBeforeSection(section);
        if (hasSectionHeaderView(section)) {
            return row - 1;
        } else {
            return row;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the cell at this index is a section header
     */
    protected boolean isSectionHeader(int position) {
        int section = getSection(position);
        return hasSectionHeaderView(section)
                && numberOfCellsBeforeSection(section) == position;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of cells (= headers + rows) before the indicated
     * section
     */
    protected int numberOfCellsBeforeSection(int section) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(numberOfSections(), section); i++) {
            if (hasSectionHeaderView(i)) {
                count += 1;
            }
            count += numberOfRows(i);
        }
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mCount = numberOfCellsBeforeSection(numberOfSections());
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetInvalidated() {
        super.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        mCount = numberOfCellsBeforeSection(numberOfSections());
    }

    @Override
    /**
     * Dispatched to call getRowItemViewType or getSectionHeaderItemViewType
     */
    public final int getItemViewType(int position) {
        int section = getSection(position);
        if (isSectionHeader(position)) {
            return getRowViewTypeCount()
                    + getSectionHeaderItemViewType(section);
        } else {
            return getRowItemViewType(section, getRowInSection(position));
        }
    }

    @Override
    /**
     * Dispatched to call getRowViewTypeCount and getSectionHeaderViewTypeCount
     */
    public final int getViewTypeCount() {
        return getRowViewTypeCount() + getSectionHeaderViewTypeCount();
    }

    @Override
    /**
     * By default, disables section headers
     */
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return !isSectionHeader(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with framelayout or relativelayout

Comment: Can you please elaborate how can I use framelayout or relative layout

Comment: Please have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959841/how-to-place-an-imageview-on-top-of-another-imageview-in-android    
or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959841/how-to-place-an-imageview-on-top-of-another-imageview-in-android

Comment: if the whole thing in the second image is just one item of a list, why don't you create a custom listview with a single xml for it's items? then inside your custom adapter you set all those information and pictures in their places.

Answer (score 4):

### **Problem**

- You want your listheader.xml to be on top of listview
- You want that each item on listView to have its own background

### **Solution**

1. To bring your `listheader.xml` on top of `listView` you should do something like this in your `main activity XML` :

   ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


     <include
       android:id="@+id/listheader"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       layout="@layout/listheader" />
     . <!-- dont forget your listheader.xml should have transparent background -->

     <ListView
       android:id="@+id/yourList"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:divider="@android:color/transparent" >
     </ListView>

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. To set `background` to your list view `items` you should do this:

   ```
    public final View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


     /**
      * I didnt have time to study your code about what happens here,
      * but I know the possible solution that you should be implemented here :)
      * Here I will post the code that puts background 
      * to listView row at this position as shown
      * in your image. So here you put your conditions for your 
      * rows that are the same as in the image above that you have shown
      * */

       if( /* put the your conditions here so that the row would be the same as in the image */ ){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow, null); // this is your listrow.xml
         // i guess your xml has as root element a relative layout
         RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) rowView .findViewById (R.id.rLayout);
          Resources res = contetx.getResources(); //resource handle
           Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.newImage);// here you put your image that you want for each row based on your row position or whatever your condition is

         rLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
       }

     }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add another layout file, say `listrowitem.xml` with `RelativeLayout` where you will put your `listheader.xml` on top of `listrow.xml`. After that, you can make your `listheader` to have `@null` background.