# How to add image background to imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I want to create this [**Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuDm7.jpg)

**My work:** [I am getting this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P99L.png)

I have created this using

```
          <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/grid_img"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:paddingBottom="3.5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="3.5dp"
                android:paddingRight="3.5dp"
                android:paddingTop="3.5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@drawable/image_frame_arc"
                android:src="@mipmap/image_1" />
```

how to overcame these space on all sides.

Comment: you have some options in android 1. consider drawing on view overlay of image view 2. stack two image views using framelayout

Comment: i try to use two image view using frame layout but these space its exists.

Comment: might be happening due to padding or non transparent areas in image.

Comment: As mentioned in answers you can use FrameLayout : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

Answer (score 2):

```
 <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ID_NAME"
            android:src="drawable/IMAGE_NAME_YOU_WANT_TO_SHOW_FROM_DRAWABLEFOLDER"

    />
```

just replace "ID_NAME" with the name you desired and your desired image name which is in drawable folder. hopes it will fine.

Answer (score 1):

What about doing like this as [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11960026/5067493),

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/image_1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image_frame_arc" />
</merge>
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
 <FrameLayout 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/grid_img"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:background="@drawable/image_frame_arc"
                android:padding="3.5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@mipmap/image_1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/number"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </FrameLayout>
```