# How to set an Image Relative to another Image View

Tags: android, user-interface, imageview

I want to set an image on another image .
The base image is of 3600px X 2400px (WxH)
The image I want to insert has these conditions:-
X: 471px
Y: 282px
W: 1053px
H: 936px
 X & Y are relative to the base image.
All coordinates are in px.

Comment: There are lots of questions about this. Please search first before asking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959841/how-to-place-an-imageview-on-top-of-another-imageview-in-android

Comment: I am having image size in px not in dp. The questions asked are for dp

Comment: @SharadDadhich That doesn't change the answer.  Although doing things in exact locations like that are unlikely to work well across multiple screen sizes and should generally be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Using a RelativeLayout below one another and some margins (maybe padding will fit) I ommited the android: in all parameters.

```
<RelativeLayout layout_width="wrap_content" layout_height="wrap_content">
   <ImageView
      id="@+id/firstOne"
      layout_width="360px" layout_height="240px" />
   <ImageView
      belowOf="@+id/firstOne"
      marginTop="28px"
      marginLeft="47px"
      layout_width="105px" layout_height="93px" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I downsized all values by 10 so you can see the result, but you will need to find a relative solution with wrap_contents + adjustViewBounds and scaleMatrix = fitXY

Comment: This image size goes out of the window size

Comment: Yes, you specified exactly values in px, you better using some relative sizes

Comment: i downsized things to you see this answer working as expected

Comment: Ya the thing here is working in small size but i am restricted to work for the provided Image Sizes. Can you provide a solution for the same ?

Comment: You need to scale down anyway

Answer (score 0):

Use a FrameLayout. Generally, a FrameLayout is used to hold a single child view otherwise it is difficult.
[See the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)