# How to place two views inside a layout in the exact same position and size ratio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-gui

I want to place those two parts inside a layout to form a loading bar.

[image: wood board]

and
[image: loading indicator]

The orange indicator needs to be inside the wood board,
But I can't find a way to connect them in a proper way...

The final results should look like this
 [image: this].

XML File:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wood_board"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.menwithandroid.myhookah.gui.LoadingProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/loading_indicator"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I connect those parts properly?
Thanks.

Comment: you can easily achieve this using RelativeLayout, give same relation to the views, but question is what do you want to do this ? i mean do you want to show loader on Image view ?

Comment: The indicator should be inside the socket (on the wood board), so I need to apply margins or another value to determine its location. But I can't use dp or px because it will be messed up on other screen sizes...

Comment: Have the images with the same ratio.. meaning the orange part have the necessary transparent space around this way just you put them within the same parentview

Answer (score 1):

with constraint layouts its very easy... you can place items in the same exact position, and the use android:elevation to ensure that one component is overlays the other.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wood_board"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:src="@drawable/loading"
    android:elevation="2dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/loading_indicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/wood_board"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/wood_board" />
```

Your solution will look something like this: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOTRB.png)

[image: picture]

Answer (score 0):

It is just imageview inside imageview.The following may work for you.[This is the sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959841/how-to-place-an-imageview-on-top-of-another-imageview-in-android) or you can just drag in design section of xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Try it out with a `RelativeLayout` something like this:

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

           <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/wood_board"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <com.menwithandroid.myhookah.gui.LoadingProgressBar
           android:id="@+id/loading_indicator"
            android:gravity="center"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

And then set the `ImageView` size accordingly, which would fit into the `LoadingProgressBar`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all...

I used `android.support.constraint.Guideline` with `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent` to determine the location of the indicator inside the wood board by percentages (for different screen sizes compatibility).

It ends up looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWjQs.png)