# Bottom Align Floating Action Button - Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm simply trying to do this alignment with constraintlayout but I'm not sure It's possible or not.

How can I do it ?

[image: Sample]

Sample xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_portrait" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
```

My workaround.

[image: My possible workaround.]

Comment: what do you mean by is it allowed or not ?

Comment: It's generally done with coordinator layout. I meant is it possible and if it's possible is it the right way.

Comment: Yes everything is possible, it's not wrong until or unless it is completing your requirements. It's possible and I believe you already have achieved it. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39267214/4407266

Comment: @Umair if you meant my workaround it will probably shown different at different screens.

Comment: @EmreAkcan yes that's because it will adjust itself according to different screen sizes but the layout will remain the same.

Comment: @Umair So floating button's position on imageview will be same at every screen with my second adjustment?

Comment: @EmreAkcan ah nope it won't why because every screen has a different resolution so on bigger screens it will go down. Your best bet is to use framelayout of use relative layout inside constraintlayout.

Comment: @EmreAkcan Using *Frame Layout* will be effective for all resolutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constraining both the top and the bottom of the `FloatingActionButton` to the bottom of the `ImageView` will center it on the edge. Also `android:layout_width="match_parent"` of the `ImageView` should be changed to `0dp` to enforce horizontal constraints. Example `XML` looks like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_portrait" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with constraint layout with the following code.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/carrick" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="176dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bcslogo" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

otherwise you can use relative layout instead of constraint you can place your all content in relative layout like following

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/notesbg"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/myRecyclernote"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/myFAB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            app:backgroundTint="#00b4ed"
            android:src="@drawable/floatingbtn"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:elevation="8dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You have used        `android:layout_marginBottom="176dp"`
so your code looks different on my screen.

Comment: then you can try with relative layout otherwise your floating button will display just below of image

Comment: No, look the plaskoff's answer.